# Creating list with spring ResultSet

Tags: spring, postgresql, java-8

I need help to create a list of Contacts using `ResultSet` and Java 8.

I need to filter the list by name, only if the name is suitable then add it to the list. And set `fetchSize` to work with a million rows from Postgres.

For example:

```
public List <Contact> getAll (String nameFilter) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile (nameFilter);

        List <Contact> contacts = new ArrayList <> ();

        JdbcTemplate.query ("SELECT * FROM contacts", rs -> {
// here it is necessary maybe to do something like this !pattern.matcher(name).matches()
// and maybe jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize (*how many rows will be better to read from
// postgres? (5,5000,50000 ???) *)
            Contacts.add (new Contact (rs.getInt ("id"), rs.getString ("name")));
        });

        return contacts;

    }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the fetch size before running the query. Bear in mind that if you use the a singleton [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) object it is going affect all your queries, and you should set this configuration when the `JdbcTemplate` object is created.

About creating the list, using the functional interface [ResultSetExtractor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE_to_4.0.0.M1/Spring%20Framework%203.2.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html), something like this should work:

```
springJdbcTemplate.query ("SELECT * FROM contacts", rs -> {
  while(rs.next()) {
    if (pattern.matcher(rs.getString("name")).matches())
      contacts.add (new Contact (rs.getInt ("id"), rs.getString ("name")));
  }
  return null;
});
```

It suffices to say that if you could translate the pattern into the sql query it would be much faster.

Comment: A big fetch size means you are going to ask less times the database when the rowset becomes exhausted but you need more memory to keep it. With a small fetch size you are going to ask the database more often but you need less memory. So it depends on how big the results you are expecting is and what you need. Speed? Memory? That is your decision.